# Pulsed current measurement and power factor calculation

Tags: power-electronics, power-factor-correction, rms

I want to measure pulsed current in a 3-phase power meter application. I understand that the waveform will be random, as the current in question is the overall current consumed by different types of devices SMPS or not. My initial idea is to use an ADC with a very high sampling frequency to capture max points, then calculate RMS current (using root mean square equation, with 20ms integration period) with a microntroller or dsp.

*My first question is how to select a proper ADC for this task
(max sampling frequency required) ?

*My second question would be about power factor, how to calculate real power and apparent power ?

Comment: You need first "synchro" ADC which can sample multiple signals at the same time.

Comment: Is this for one or more phases?

Comment: @ChesterGillon for three phases

Comment: Then you must use a 6 channels (minimum) sampling ADC ...

Comment: @Issam H Please [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/695552/edit) the question to say this is for three phases. Have you looked at microprocessor based reference designs such as [Class 0.5 Three-Phase Smart Meter Reference Design](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDM-THREEPHASEMETER-F67641) or [Low-Cost Three-Phase Electricity Meter Reference Design](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDM-THREEPHASEMETER-F449) to see if their features and performance could be a starting point to meet your requirements?

Comment: @ChesterGillon thanks for sharing these, I will check them thoroughly. My issue was with max recommended sampling frequency, and I assumed it will be the same for all phases, that's why I didn't mention this detail

Comment: @Antonio51 can you share a part number of one of these "synchro" ADCs ? analog devices website says they measure angular position and velocity, not sure if this is what you are referring to

Comment: @IssamH "synchro" misused ... Should be "simultaneous" sampling (include a track/hold for the samples. Something like https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad7865.html#product-overview but for at least 6 or 8 inputs ... https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad7656a.html

Comment: Or the "new" https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad4858.html

Comment: @Antonio51 thank you very much, they seem interesting